# R generated graph from Kaggle notebook that's completely different from the graph I get from RStudio

Tags: r, visualization, kaggle

The following code creates a bar chart for my analysis:

```
ggplot(ctd_monthly_num_rides,
       aes(x=factor(month,level=
                      c('January','February','March',
                        'April', 'May','June',
                        'July','August','September',
                        'October','November','December')),
           # Orders x-axis chronologically instead
           # of using the default alphabetic order.
           y=number_of_rides,
           fill=member_casual)) +
  facet_wrap(~rideable_type) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=.65,position='dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=label_number(suffix = 'K', scale = 1e-3)) +
  # Changes y-axis to list full numbers of rides in thousands (K)
  # instead of scientific notation (i.e. 4e+05).
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45)) +
  # Changes angle for each name of month in x-axis.
  labs(title='Number of Rides by Each User Type & Month',
       fill='User Type') +
  # Adds title and changes legend label.
  xlab('') +
  ylab('Number of Rides')
# Changes x and y-axis labels for better legibility.
```

However, the graph generated through Kaggle looks like:
[image]

What I got (and what I want to see) from RStudio is very different like:

[image]

Is there a way to manipulate it to make it look exactly like how I see it in RStudio? Maybe extend the width of the graph that's generated from the notebook?

Comment: It looks like the data you are trying to plot is different. The data in the Kaggle image doesn't have any month names. What does `table(ctd_monthly_num_rides$month)`  return in the two different systems?

Comment: Could be that `month` became all `NA` when coercing to `factor`, if they were coded differently. But we can't tell without a reproducible example.